# Custom consumer implementation factory with Microsoft Dependency Injection

Tags: masstransit

Is there a way to register Consumer like the service below:

```
services.AddTransient < IMyService > (provider => {
  return new MyServiceImplementation(2);
});
```

with `AddConsumer<T>()` method?

What I need is a custom implementation of Consumer factory because it will be injected with a different instance of one of its dependencies depending on the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit registers the consumer added via `AddConsumer` as shown below:

```cs
collection.AddScoped<T>();
```

You're welcome to create your own register *after* configuring MassTransit, which should replace the one registered by MassTransit. In your example above, it could be something like:

```cs
services.AddScoped<TConsumer>(provider =>
{
    var options = provider.GetService<SomeOptions>();
    if (options.UseFirst)
        return new TConsumer(provider.GetRequiredService<Impl1>()
    
    return new TConsumer(provider.GetRequiredService<Impl2>()
});
```

You get the picture, right?